# Converting a table of html inputs to PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I am trying to get the information from a html table into an php array. It is very easy to do with the following method:

```
function getdata($table)
{
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML($table);

    $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    function tdrows($elements)
    {
        $str = "";
        foreach ($elements as $element)
        {
            $str .= $element->nodeValue . ", ";
        }
        return $str;
    }
    foreach ($items as $node)
    {
        echo tdrows($node->childNodes) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

The problem I am now facing is the content of the table has html inputs and I want just the value of those inputs. The table is of the form:

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><div class="add">add</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Will I be able to modify the current function to accomplish this or should I try another approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PHP is server-side, you will not be able to get the value of the input unless you submit this inputted value to the server, for example using post or get when the form is submitted. You should use Javascript if you want the value of the input without having to submit the form. If this doesn't answer your question please try to ask it more clearly : )

Comment: nope that is the answer I was looking for, makes sense, thank you